# How to extract midi note numbers from a midi file?

Tags: midi

I'm trying to figure out how to extract the midi note number information from a midi file. Is there any software that can do this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because 1) This is a question better suited to a computer programming site, and 2) software recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: My two cents on this: Midi is a binary file. Midi commands are 3 bytes. In the file, go look for 0x90 (note on) commands followed by a Midi Note Number. Here's some detailed info about the complete format and a table for Midi Note Numbers: http://www.music.mcgill.ca/~ich/classes/mumt306/StandardMIDIfileformat.html and also: follow Aaron's suggestion, find elaborate answers on [StackOverflow - Search Midi](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Midi) there are lots of MIDI libraries for every thinkable language, to make life easier.

Comment: Looking for 0x90 is a bad idea. Please see my [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44177751/2975589). Definitely a dedicated library should be used.

Comment: @Aaron It's not off-topic, the answer would have been: MIDI files are binary files that need a software program to parse them and extract the information. This is a music-related piece of knowledge and it is not trivially self-evident, it is a question that needs to be asked and answered and understood.